# Since moving to 64bit, I get access violations from nvoglv64.dll on random glVertexAttribArray calls

Tags: c++, opengl

What it says on the title really. Moved across all my libs and includes to 64bit to enable me to use assimp in 64bit, but now I randomly get access violations from nvogl64.dll. It's always on `glVertexAttribPointer` calls, but random, sometimes I can run a whole 30 mins, most of the time it's the very first or second time it's called. What could I be doing wrong? Here's my VAO generating method for completeness.

```
GLuint vertsVBO = 0;
GLuint normsVBO = 0;
GLuint textsVBO = 0;

GLuint shapeVAO = 0;

//Make the VAO
glGenVertexArrays(1, &shapeVAO);
glBindVertexArray(shapeVAO);


//Setup the Vertex buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &vertsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float*)*uniqueVertexes * 3, indexedPoints, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


//The normal Buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &normsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float*)*uniqueVertexes * 3, indexedNorms, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


//and the texture co-ord buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &textsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float*)*uniqueVertexes * 2, indexedTexts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(8, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(8);


glGenBuffers(1, &tangentsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tangentsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float*)*uniqueVertexes * 4, indexedTangents, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

glGenBuffers(1, &bitangentsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bitangentsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float*)*uniqueVertexes * 4, indexedBitangents, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);

glGenBuffers(1, &indicesVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesLength * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


//Unbind VAO
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure about this?

```cpp
sizeof(float*)
```

I'd have imagined you'd be loading floats (rather than pointers)

```cpp
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*uniqueVertexes * 3, indexedNorms, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: That seems to have done it. Don't know how I didn't see it. That'll have worked on a 32bit machine as sizeof(float*) will of course been 4 bytes, but 8 bytes on a 64bit machine, causing the error. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @WillHain heh didn't see it till now (have you edited the comment (updates sometimes take time to propagate through servers)? but most likely it was just too early in the morning for me :) and I stopped on the `Don't know how I didn't see it` it happens to me time to time...)